# Recursively search javascript Global Execution Context

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, script-debugging

I'd like to do this in Chrome Developer Tools, but I'd take anything at this point.

## The question

If I know I am looking for a specific object, how can I search the entire JS hierarchy to find it?

## The situation

In know from my time on irc://irc.freenode.net/bash that when people reduce their question to what they think they should do, they waste a lot of time.

I use Confluence Cloud and their WYSIWYG is terrible. Because it is TinyMCE, I can get *a lot* done by editing the DOM in the Chrome Developer Tools. I ought to be able to hack the JS object and get even more through. But, the first step is the find the TinyMCE.settings object.

Comment: Try [How to search the browser window object looking which object or variable has the searched-for value?](//stackoverflow.com/a/46536947)

Comment: Thanks, that's a pretty good lead. What I actually need is to search based on object name rather than value. I'll try to convert that over, but I'm going to leave this open until I do.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a reference to the object's constructor, the [`queryObjects()`](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/08/devtools-release-notes#query-objects) API might be able to help you locate the object. You might need to set a breakpoint and pause the code at a point where you know that the object still exists in the heap.

Check what version of Chrome you're using at `chrome://version`. `queryObjects()` was introduced in Chrome 62, which should be hitting [Stable](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel#TOC-How-do-I-choose-which-channel-to-use-) right about now but you might not have it quite yet.